# Why wont my create-react-app content center?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I used create-react-app and have been playing around with it. I understand the "app" class is supposed to center the content, and it did when I barely  anything. But now it isn't doing that. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/home";
import About from "./pages/about";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
    </Router> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

about.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Breadcrumb, Card } from "react-bootstrap"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

function About() {
    return (

        <div className="app">
            <h1>ABOUT PAGE</h1> 
            <a href="/">
            <img src="https://www.searchpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Back-Arrow-Icon-PNG-715x715.png" height="50px" />
          </a> 
          <Card className="mb-3" style={{ color: "#000"}}>
              <Card.Img/>
              <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>
                  Card Example
              </Card.Title>  
              <Card.Text>
                  This is an example of react bootstrap cards
              </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Breadcrumb>
          <Breadcrumb.Item>Test</Breadcrumb.Item>
          <Breadcrumb.Item>Test 2</Breadcrumb.Item>
          <Breadcrumb.Item>Test 3</Breadcrumb.Item>
          </Breadcrumb>
          <Button variant="success">Test Button</Button>
        </div>

    )
}

export default About;
```

Comment: Centering the content is one of the basic things that you need CSS to do, I'd advise you to spend more time studying basics (HTML, CSS, JS) before using frameworks or libraries

Answer (score 0):

In create-react-app, there is a file App.css with class `.App`:

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you'd like to use it, you will have to use capitalized name of the class, since that's how it is defined in css file.

Comment: Thats already there. I also tried ```justify-content: center```.